# Escape single quote in regex in Hive

Tags: hive

I'm trying since yesterday to write a regex in hive

```
Select regexp_extract(MyColumn,'Clôture de l''intervention(.*)"typeid"',0) as MyColumn
from MyTable
```

This regex return an empty result but it should return something.

if i try it this way, shorter way :

```
Select regexp_extract(MyColumn,'Clôture de l(.*)"typeid"',0) as MyColumn
from MyTable
```

It returns something so i guess the problem is the single quote.

How can i escape it to include it in my regex ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a "\'".  That is a [backslash][quote].  But also remember you can also be lazy and just use "." which will match any single character, but often works as a good cheat for situations like this.

You should use:

```
regexp_extract(com_lib,'Clôture de l\'intervention(.*)"typeid"',0)
```

or

```
regexp_extract(com_lib,'Clôture de l.intervention(.*)"typeid"',0)
```

Example using spark but just an example of it working. (And is escaped as a string so works a little different.)

```
>>> spark.sql("select regexp_extract('Clôture de l\\'intervention122342\"typeid\"','Clôture de l\\'intervention(.*)\"typeid\"',1) ").show()
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|regexp_extract(Clôture de l'intervention122342"typeid", Clôture de l'intervention(.*)"typeid", 1)|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                           122342|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But this does show you how to work on your regexp to make it work.  Start simple:

```
select 'Clôture de l'
```

This should work out of the box and is easy.  Then play with it until adding a character at time until you get the syntax correct

```
select 'Clôture de l\''
```

Once you have it correct as a string then move it into regexp and again add a character at a time making it work.

```
select regexp_extract( 'Clôture de l\'intervention' 'Clôture de l\'',0)
```

You don't need to run on a table, just use a string and slowly add characters to one by one to make it work.

Comment: i can't figure out how to write it 

`regexp_extract(com_lib,'Clôture de l"\'"intervention(.*)"typeid"',0)`

Comment: Updated my answer I'm sorry the " was just to denote the fix not part of the solution.